# Programmatic Access to VBA Sheet Module from Visual Basic

Tags: excel, vba

We have a Visual Basic script that generates an XLSM file from an XML file. I'm able to import bas and cls files, but I can't get it to add or import VBA code to a specific sheet.

I use the following to import a module:
oXL.VBE.ExcelBook.VBComponents.Import("filepath.cls"), and have tried several ways to get this to be added to a specific sheet unsuccessfully. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: It is possible, but tricky, plus it is required that you trust the access to the VBA project object model (Trust Center, Macro settings) and that is a security issue and often blocked in corporate environments. Alternative is that you create a template sheet with the code in the workbook where your code runs and copy that sheet into the new file.

Comment: You cannot *import* code to an excel object. You have to write it to the `codemodule`.

Comment: It should work if `Attribute VB_Name = "Worksheet2"` is set to a valid sheet name - and you have to specify the full filename

Comment: [this may be of use](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/import-method-vba-add-in-object-model)